# Problems with counting in a recursive function without adding a parameter (Java)

Tags: java, recursion

I apologize if this has been answered already but the only answers I could find involved adding a parameter called count.

My assignment asks us to count the number of items in a linked list using recursion.

Here is what I tried (note I am using an array because I have one created and I have a lot more to do tonight:

```
public static int countArray(int[] array, int first, int last)
{
    int count;

    if(first < last)
    {
        countArray(array, first + 1, last);
    }

    return (count + 1);
}
```

This, as expected, returns 2 even though the length of the array is 10. I have also tried setting count to 1 but that just resets it (also as expected) every time the function is called. I am sure there is something obvious I am missing but I just can't figure out what it is. Thanks!

Comment: You should assign the `count` before the method,or it would be init as zero everytime

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public static int countArray(int[] array, int first, int last){
    if(first < last){
        return 1+countArray(array, first + 1, last);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Giving away the answer on a homework assignment?  Not a great way to help this person learn.

Comment: StackOverflow is awesome!! Thank you! That worked. I had to change < to <= and it doesn't seem to be causing any problems so I think I've got it!

Is this pretty much the way you handle counting in a recursive function? I don't see any other way to increment a variable...

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases you should handle:

- The empty list, which has length 0
- The non-empty list, which has length (1 + the length of the list minus the first element)

Instead of removing the first element, you of course also could remove the last one.